# onkeypress does not working fine in Firefox?

Tags: javascript

The following code works fine in all browser except Firefox. Fails when maximum length reached it does not allows backspace and delete also.

```
     function textboxMultilineMaxNumber(txt, maxLen) {
      try {
        if (txt.value.length > (maxLen - 1)) return false;
         } catch (e) {
       }
    }
```

Comment: Are you talking about Mozilla Firefox or really just Mozilla?

Comment: Could you add the code that actually handles the keypress event?

Answer (score 0):

`onkeypress` does not trigger on backspace and delete as it is supposed to respresent a character that is typed. You should be using `onkeydown` which triggered the moment the user presses a key and works on all keys.

Answer (score 0):

The keypress event is designed for handling the a character typed by the user rather than detecting keyboard activity and the delete and backspace keys do not generate characters